# finding n-1 matrix elements in R

Tags: r

probably it's a very simple question with a very simple answer but I just can't figure it out by myself. I have a matrix called 'hz' with 1 column and 115 rows (hz[1:115, 1]) and I'm trying to find the values preceding those that are smaller than 1 and replace them. I did the following: 
`hz[c(hz < 1)]`, got 11 values,
then I tried to find the preceding ones: `hz[c(hz < 1) - 1]`, expected 11 values but got 114.
If I try to find specific elements like `hz[c(6, 26, 36)]`, and the preceding ones: `hz[c(6, 26, 36) - 1]` I got 3 values in both cases as expected. So what's the difference? Is it a problem that I have a condition (<1) in the index?

Thank you for your help!

Viktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want `hz[which(hz < 1) - 1]`.

Note, `hz < 1` is returning a logical vector, i.e., `TRUE` / `FALSE`. If you take subtraction: `(hz < 1) - 1`, `TRUE` will be seen as `1` and `FALSE` will be seen as `0`. Applying `which` to a logical vector gives you positions (as integers) of `TRUE`, which is what you want.

Consider the following demonstration:

```
x <- 1:5

x < 3
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

(x < 3) - 1
#[1]  0  0 -1 -1 -1

which(x < 3)
#[1] 1 2

which(x < 3) - 1
#[1] 0 1
```